# MySQL Query: Getting distinct values for this query

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch all distinct user_ids with an item_id=100 AND item_id=200. The correct result in this case would be 1. But how would my SQL-query look like in this simplified case? 
Table:

```
user_id    item_id
1          100
1          200
3          100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM yourTable
WHERE item_id IN (100, 200)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 2;
```

This trick first restricts to only records corresponding to your two items of interest, then it asserts that a matching user has a distinct item count of two, implying that he meets the criteria.

Sometimes logic requires doing this in a slightly different way:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_id = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_id = 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

This form can be more useful in certain situations, but it does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I need here. Also thanks to P.Salmon for the same solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
    CREATE table t(user_id int,   item_id int);
    insert into t values
    (1     ,     100),
    (1     ,     200),
    (3     ,     100);


    select user_id
    from t 
    where item_id in (100, 200)
    group by user_id having count(distinct item_id) = 2;

+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use self-join (intuitively easier to understand):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.user_id) 
FROM table_name AS t1 inner join table_name AS t2 
ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id 
WHERE t1.item_id=100 and t2.item_id=200;
```

Comment: Good answer.  Note that `DISTINCT` will also require an aggregation step.

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you! So the other solution would have a slight performance advantage?

Comment: It's tough to say, and would depend on indices you have, and maybe even the data in your table.